# Histogram based on frequent/common words

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to create a histogram based on frequent/common words, but I only get errors when running the code. I managed to find the 10 most common words, but I can't visualize it in a histogram.

```
description_list = df['description'].values.tolist()

from collections import Counter
Counter(" ".join(description_list).split()).most_common(10)

#histogram 
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.title("10 most frequent tokens in description")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Words")
plt.show
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this missed a few things:

1. The result of `Counter(...).most_common(10)` was not assigned to `x` or `y`
2. `x`, `y` appear to be unbound
3. `plt.show` was not invoked, so it either does nothing or prints something like `<function show at 0x...>`

Here's a reproducible example that fixes these:

```py
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "description": [
        "This is the first example",
        "This is the second example",
        "This is similar to the first two",
        "This exists add more words"
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


description_list = df['description'].values.tolist()

# Assign the Counter instance `most_common` call to a variable:
word_frequency = Counter(" ".join(description_list).split()).most_common(10)

# `most_common` returns a list of (word, count) tuples
words = [word for word, _ in word_frequency]
counts = [counts for _, counts in word_frequency]

plt.bar(words, counts)
plt.title("10 most frequent tokens in description")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.xlabel("Words")
plt.show()
```

With expected output:

[image: Expected output of code is a bar chart showing 10 most frequent words. The word 'This' occurs four times, 'exists' occurs a single time.]